# Toggle images hide/visible in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the thing, I want some of the pictures in my HTML file to be hidden at first leaving a black at its position. And it's shown after clicking on it. I can put js code in my layout file but to keep the code clean and extremely readable, there shouldn't be div span tags or id or class, just add parameters like 'onclick' in img tags.

Current code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function toggle_visibility() {
        if ( this.style.visibility == 'hidden' )
           this.style.visibility = 'visible';
        else
           this.style.visibility = 'hidden';
     }
 </script>



 <img onclick="toggle_visibility();" src="IMG.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Please update the question with your existing code

Comment: "I can put js code in my layout file" How? Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Add specific class to each element that needs that functionality. In my example this class is 'image'.

Also you need to have draggable set to false for images, else you can still see the image when dragging.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('image')) {
        e.target.style.filter = 'brightness(100%)';
    }
});
```

```css
img.image {
    height: 100px;
    filter: brightness(0%);
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://stepupandlive.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/3d-animated-frog-image.jpg"/ draggable="false">
<img class="image" src="https://dictionary.cambridge.org/images/thumb/chick_noun_002_06563.jpg?version=4.0.44"/ draggable="false">
```